# OpenLayers remove current marker before adding new

Tags: javascript, web, openlayers

I'm trying to develop a web application with a tag location feature using openlayers. I want to add a maximum of one marker to the map when it is clicked. When the user clicked on the map for the second time, the previous marker will be deleted. But, I can't find an appropriate way to remove the marker before adding the new one. [Remove added marker before adding new marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304615/remove-added-marker-before-adding-new-marker)

I know this question is already asked, but I have the same problem in different code. I tried everything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304615/remove-added-marker-before-adding-new-marker) and nothing worked.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })];

            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                view: new ol.View({
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: [166326, 5992663]
                }),
                interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, pinchRotate: false }),
                layers: layers
            });

            var search = new ol.control.SearchPhoton({
                lang: "fr",
                reverse: true,
                position: true
            });
            map.addControl(search);

            search.on('select', function (e) {
                const a = e.coordinate[0];
                let b = e.coordinate[1];

                map.getView().animate({
                    center: e.coordinate,
                    zoom: Math.max(map.getView().getZoom(), 16)
                });

                map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
                    if (layer.get('name') && layer.get('name') == 'markers') {
                        map.removeLayer(layer)
                    }
                });

                var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                    style: new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 1],
                            src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                        })
                    })
                });

                map.addLayer(markers);

                var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
                markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);

                //console.log(markers);
            });


            

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a layer with a property value you need to assign it when the layer is created

```
            var markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                properties: {name: 'markers'},
                source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        anchor: [0.5, 1],
                        src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                    })
                })
            });
```

It would be easier to use a global variable for the layer

```
        var markers;
        search.on('select', function (e) {
            const a = e.coordinate[0];
            let b = e.coordinate[1];

            map.getView().animate({
                center: e.coordinate,
                zoom: Math.max(map.getView().getZoom(), 16)
            });

            if (markers) {
                map.removeLayer(markers)
            }

            markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        anchor: [0.5, 1],
                        src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                    })
                })
            });

            map.addLayer(markers);

            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
            markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);

            //console.log(markers);
        });
```